# Separate the words in the sentence for text classification problem

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, text-classification

I am solving a text classification problem and while annotating my data I found very long words which are sentence itself but are not separated by space.

One of the example which I found while annotating my data point is:

Throughnumerousacquisitionsandtransitions,Anacompstillexiststodaywithagreaterfocusondocumentmanagement

Desired output:

Through numerous acquisitions and transitions, Anacomp still exists today with a greater focus on document management.

I have looked upon various frameworks such as Keras, PyTorch to see if they provide any functionality to solve this issue but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you are trying to solve is text/word segmentation. It is possible to approach this based on ML using a sequence model (such as LSTM) and a word embedding (such as BERT).

[This link](http://nlpprogress.com/chinese/chinese_word_segmentation.html%20details) details such an approach for Chinese language. Chinese language does not adopt spaces, so this sort of approach is necessary as a preprocessing component in Chinese NLP processing tasks.

I would like to describe an automaton based approach using [Aho-Corasick Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm).

First do a `pip install pyahocorasick`

I'm resorting to use only the words in your input string for the sake of demonstration. In a real world scenario you could just use a dictionary of words from something like [Wordnet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/).

```
import ahocorasick

automaton = ahocorasick.Automaton()

input = 'Throughnumerousacquisitionsandtransitions, Anacompstillexiststodaywithagreaterfocusondocumentmanagement'

# Replace this with a large dictionary of words
word_dictionary = ['Through', 'numerous', 'acquisition', 'acquisitions', 'and', 'transitions', 'Anacomp', 'still',
                   'exists', 'today', 'with', 'a', 'greater', 'focus', 'on', 'document', 'management']

# add dictionary words to automaton
for idx, key in enumerate(word_dictionary):
    automaton.add_word(key, (idx, key))

# Build aho-corasick automaton for search
automaton.make_automaton()

# to check for ambiguity, if there is a longer match then prefer that
previous_rng = range(0, 0)
previous_rs = set(previous_rng)

# Holds the end result dictionary
result = {}

# search the inputs using automaton
for end_index, (insert_order, original_value) in automaton.iter(input):
    start_index = end_index - len(original_value) + 1
    current_rng = range(start_index, end_index)
    current_rs = set(current_rng)
    # ignore previous as there is a longer match available
    if previous_rs.issubset(current_rs):
        # remove ambiguous short entry in favour of the longer entry
        if previous_rng in result:
            del result[previous_rng]
        result[current_rng] = (insert_order, original_value)
        previous_rng = current_rng
        previous_rs = current_rs
    # if there is no overlap of indices, then its a new token, add to result
    elif previous_rs.isdisjoint(current_rs):
        previous_rng = current_rng
        previous_rs = current_rs
        result[current_rng] = (insert_order, original_value)
    # ignore current as it is a subset of previous
    else:
        continue
    assert input[start_index:start_index + len(original_value)] == original_value

for x in result:
    print(x, result[x])
```

Produces results :

```
range(0, 6) (0, 'Through')
range(7, 14) (1, 'numerous')
range(15, 26) (3, 'acquisitions')
range(27, 29) (4, 'and')
range(30, 40) (5, 'transitions')
range(43, 49) (6, 'Anacomp')
range(50, 54) (7, 'still')
range(55, 60) (8, 'exists')
range(61, 65) (9, 'today')
range(66, 69) (10, 'with')
range(71, 77) (12, 'greater')
range(78, 82) (13, 'focus')
range(83, 84) (14, 'on')
range(85, 92) (15, 'document')
range(93, 102) (16, 'management')
```